# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of null ExtJS 4.0.7

Tags: dom, extjs

I am getting this error while trying to render a **table** using ExtJS. The table is rendering as expected but I am not able to figure out the reason for error. This happens only while rendering a table. If I replace all the `autoEl` to `div` the error does not appear anymore.

[image: Rendered Table image]

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of null

Below is the code to render table

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'AM',

  // appFolder: 'app',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create("Ext.Container", {
      autoEl: "div",
      cls: "card",
      items: [{
        xtype: "container",
        autoEl: "div",
        cls: "row",
        style: {
          "margin-left": "20px",
          "margin-right": "20px"
        },
        items: [{
          xtype: "container",
          autoEl: "table",
          cls: "table table-hover table-striped",
          items: [{
            xtype: "container",
            autoEl: "thead",
            id: "tablethead",
            items: [{
              xtype: "container",
              autoEl: "tr",
              items: [{
                xtype: "component",
                autoEl: "th",
                html: "ROW"
              }]
            }]
          }, {
            xtype: "container",
            autoEl: "tbody",
            items: [{
              xtype: "container",
              autoEl: "tr",
              items: [{
                xtype: "component",
                autoEl: "td",
                html: "CELL"
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }],
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't do it like that. Just render all the markup you need in a single component.

Comment: I would like to separate out each component of a table into it's own to handle various events specifically and styling.

Comment: It's a bad idea, it's going to be expensive. Also, containers have their own markup structures that you'll be fighting with.

Comment: But how would I handle events at each level? Could you please share a minimal working sample if possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "events at each level"?

Comment: Like, when I click on a header cell, I want to fire a certain event and on a normal cell, another event etc. The posted code is not the final result, I am just experimenting.

Comment: Just render the table into a single component and use event delegation to filter out the targets and fire the correct events.

Comment: Something like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2d56